# Unable to allocate Numpy in Python

Tags: python, csv, memory, pycharm, allocation

I am reading in a 15Gb .csv file using the read_csv() pandas function including the iterator/chunk functionality because I need a subset of the file of about 20%.

I am doing this in PyCharm where I set the max heap size to 18Gb (although I have 16Gb RAM) and the minimum allocated memory to half of the max heap size 9Gb. Throughout this process Pycharm indicates I am using around 100Mb to 200Mb of RAM, while the Windows Task Manager indicates I am using approximately 2.5Gb of RAM which includes both the PyCharm and Python processes. I have about 45% left of my memory in the task manager.

As far as I can see there is nothing that indicates that I am running out of memory. Still while reading in this data I get a Memory error which tells me:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (4, 8193780) and data type float64
```

Is there someone that can clarify this for me? I would suspect that maybe the final dataframe is larger than my RAM can handle? That would be:

```
( 4 * 8193780 * 8 (float64) ) / (1024**3) < 1Gb
```

So the above also does not seem to be the problem, or am I missing something here?

Comment: If you have 16GB of ram, I am sure a good portion of it is already in use by other applications. 15GB of flat file read into memory using pandas will require additional memory during the processing. For example trying to guess data type etc. On top of that, once the data is read, the dataframe object should be created which itself adds a lot of functionality to the data so more memory needed. You can't fit this data in memory. I can only think of [`dask`](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-every-data-scientist-should-use-dask-81b2b850e15b) here

Comment: About 45% of the memory is taken by other applications. I would expect that if I take 20% of the 15Gb file that the remaining RAM would be sufficient. I have also included specification of the data types by the way.

Comment: Did you specify the number of rows to use in `read_csv`?

Comment: No because I need to go through the whole file to check for which rows the condition for my 20% subset holds.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using 15 Gb of memory just to read your file, since i guess the read_csv() function access the whole file even if you specified the chunk/iterator to use 20% percent of your file, excluding that you are runninig windows and pycharm which needs at least 1 Gb of memory, so adding all the things up then you are out of memory i guess.

But those are someways to face your problem.

- Verify the dtype of your array, and try to find the best one for your purpose.  For example  you are using float64, consider whether float32 or even float16 might be appropriate.
- Consider if your computation can be done on a subset of the data.  This is called subsampling.  Maybe using subsampling you get a good enough model (this may be the case for a clustering algorithm like Kmean).
- You may search for out-of-core solutions.  This may either be rethinking your algorithm (can you split the work), or trying a solution that does it transparently.

Comment: Could you specify how you got to the 15.628395080566406 Gb?

Comment: can't you split the csv file into two files?